# UITableView header is overlapping the content of its cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am working on a `UITableViewController` view that has a bunch of content in the `UITableView` header of varying height. The height requirement of the entire header will vary, so I need to set it dynamically based on which content is displayed in there.

Below is what I have been trying after searching for potential solutions. The `UITableView.automaticDimension` doesn't seem to be doing anything. Setting `tableView.sectionHeaderHeight` to a static number works, but I can't quite get it to be set dynamically.

This is all being done programmatically.

Am I going about this the correct way? Basically after all the subviews have been added to the headerView I want to set the height of the entire header.

ViewDidLoad:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self as! UITableViewDataSource
        tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 200;
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
```

Supposed to be setting the header height?

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
```

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 200
    }
```

Adding the header content:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let v = headerView
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.addSubview(headingLabel)
        v.addSubview(subheadingLabel)
        v.addSubview(additionalContent)
        headerConstraints()
        return v
    }
```

This is what I see:
[image: This is what I see]

This is what I'm kind of hoping to see:
[image: This is what I'm hoping to see]

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: When you have headerView already prepared why are you using `autoHeight`? you should pass exact height. And if table style is `plain`, after scrolling down a little, header view will show over cells. Check if you are facing this behaviour and if thats the case I suggest you opaque header view rather than transparent.

Comment: You might need to reload table (or section, preferred) when content of headerView updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is:

```
v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

When you provide your custom view as a header/footer for the table view section, you don't need to modify the auto resizing mask on the returned view itself. To my best understanding, ***doing this breaks table view's internal setup.***

But if you register a `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` subclass as the header/footer, you have to consider that option as you are taking control of configuring the entire header/footer.

---

Now, I suppose your

```
let v = headerView
. . .
headerConstraints()
```

codes are correct. If that is so, the above change should work as expected.

---

Otherwise below is an example you can try:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let v = UIView()

    let headingLabel = UILabel(frame: .zero)
    headingLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    headingLabel.text = "View Header"
    headingLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30, weight: .heavy)
    headingLabel.textColor = .black

    let subheadingLabel = UILabel(frame: .zero)
    subheadingLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    subheadingLabel.text = "Subheader Content"
    subheadingLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .semibold)
    subheadingLabel.textColor = .gray

    let additionalLabel = UILabel(frame: .zero)
    additionalLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    additionalLabel.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    additionalLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    additionalLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .regular)
    additionalLabel.textColor = .white
    let additionalContent = UIView(frame: .zero)
    additionalContent.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    additionalContent.backgroundColor = .black
    additionalContent.addSubview(additionalLabel)
    additionalLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: additionalContent.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    additionalLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: additionalContent.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    additionalLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: additionalContent.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    additionalContent.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: additionalLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true

    let stackView = UIStackView(frame: .zero)
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.alignment = .fill
    stackView.distribution = .fill
    stackView.spacing = 8
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(headingLabel)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(subheadingLabel)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(additionalContent)
    v.addSubview(stackView)
    stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.leadingAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
    stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.trailingAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
    stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.topAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
    stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.bottomAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true

    return v
}
```

And don't forget (if you need automatic height calculation):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    . . .
    tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 100
    . . .
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution and part of your example solved my issues.

Answer (score 2):

Use UITableView style as grouped.

Comment: Changing the style did not solve the problem, for me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this can be resolved if you set the `clipsToBounds` of tableView to be true.

Using code:

```
tableView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Using interface builder:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Xuan. I added `tableView.clipsToBounds = true` to `ViewDidLoad` but it had no impact on the output.

Comment: hmm, may I know how are you setting up your tableView constraints with the subHeader label?

Comment: If you passed wrong height, `clipsToBounds` will really `clip` it.